config container registry from another resource group in azure.yaml fails with 404 ParentResourceNotFound
See the azure.yaml in project https://github.com/Azure-Samples/java-microservices-aca-lab/blob/main/azure.yaml
And I already have an ACR instance in another resource group, so I set the registry in the azure.yaml.
When I run command azd deploy, it fails with error ERROR CODE: ParentResourceNotFound
"message": "Failed to perform 'action' on resource(s) of type 'registries/listBuildSourceUploadUrl', because the parent resource '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-yyy/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/crvklgqmvz4vkl2' could not be found."
The registry instance crvklgqmvz4vkl2 is in another resource group rg-zzz, my service is under resource group rg-yyy.
The debug information shows the errors come from this step
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-yyy/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/crvklgqmvz4vkl2/listBuildSourceUploadUrl?api-version=2019-06-01-preview
It directly use the same group of the services to visit the container registry.
From this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-best-practices#dedicated-resource-group, we should use dedicated container registry.
I think it is reasonable to support container registry in another resource group
